# Derivative in loss function in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, loss-function

I want to make following loss function in keras:

```
Loss = mse + double_derivative(y_pred,x_train)
```

I am not able to incorporate the derivative term. I have tried `K.gradients(K.gradients(y_pred,x_train),x_train)` but it does not help.

I am getting error message:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'op'

```python
def _loss_tensor(y_true, y_pred,x_train):
    l1 = K.mean(K.square(y_true - y_pred), axis=-1)
    sigma = 0.01
    lamda = 3
    term = K.square(sigma)*K.gradients(K.gradients(y_pred,x_train),x_train)
    l2 = K.mean(lamda*K.square(term),axis=-1)
    return l1+l2

def loss_func(x_train):
        def loss(y_true,y_pred):
            return _loss_tensor(y_true,y_pred,x_train)
        return loss

def create_model_neural(learning_rate, num_layers,
                 num_nodes, activation):

    model_neural = Sequential()

    x_train = model_neural.add(Dense(num_nod, input_dim=num_input, activation=activation))

    for i in range(num_layers-1):
        model_neural.add(Dense(num_nodes,activation=activation,name=name))

    model_neural.add(Dense(1, activation=activation))

    optimizer = SGD(lr=learning_rate)
    model_loss = loss_func(x_train=x_train)

    model_neural.compile(loss=model_loss,optimizer=optimizer)

    return model_neural
```

Comment: You have to be specific, "does not help" is quite vague. Are you getting error messages? Wrong values? Include any error messages in your question.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I am getting following error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'op'"

Comment: What is `dice`? I think you meant `loss`.

Comment: @rvinas oh yes. it is loss. thank you. edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `x_train` is always `None` and keras can't take a derivative wrt `None`. And this is happening because `model_neural.add(...)` does not return anything.

I assume that `x_train` is the input that is passed to the network. In this case `x_train` should probably be another argument of `create_model_neural` or alternatively you can try `model_neural.input` tensor.