# Tensorflow/Keras - Use NN derivative in loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, derivative, mean-square-error

I'm currently estimating the sine function using tensorflow. I'd like to include the fact that the second derivative of sinus is equal to -sinus by adding a derivative term in my loss function. I'm fairly new to tf. My current code looks like this

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from tensorflow import keras
from numpy import random

# --- Settings
x_min = 0
x_max = 2*np.pi

n_train = 64
n_test = 64

# --- Generate dataset
x_train = random.uniform(x_min, x_max, n_train)
y_train = np.sin(x_train)

x_test = random.uniform(x_min, x_max, n_test)
y_test = np.sin(x_test)

# --- Create model
model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="tanh"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="tanh"))

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="tanh"))

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)

# --- Configure learning process
model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01),
        loss=custom_loss,
        metrics=['MeanSquaredError'])

# --- Train from dataset
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

Currently the `custom_loss` function is just the normal MSE. I'd like to include the derivative of the NN-output w.r.t. the input at the point `x_test`. How can I incorporate such a term into my loss function.

I already looked up a few questions. Especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288258/derivative-in-loss-function-in-keras) question looks similar, but I can't figure out how to use the answer in my code example. Thank you for your help.