# Problem with custom loss functions to solve differential equations with Tensorflow/Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to reproduce the results from [1902.05563](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.05563). One can find an example in [this link](https://www.programmersought.com/article/4460831401/) which is solving the eq. 4 in the paper. However, they are writing the layers by hand via variables and placeholders (note that it's using tf v1). Instead of writing the network from scratch, I tried to use Keras to achieve the same thing;

```py
import numpy      as np
import tensorflow as tf
x1     = tf.keras.Input(name='x_1',shape=(1),dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation=tf.nn.sigmoid,name='l1')(x1)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation=None,name='output')(dense1)
model  = tf.keras.Model(inputs=x1,outputs=output)
model.summary()
### output
Model: "functional_42"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
x_1 (InputLayer)             [(None, 1)]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
l1 (Dense)                   (None, 10)                20        
_________________________________________________________________
output (Dense)               (None, 1)                 11        
=================================================================
Total params: 31
Trainable params: 31
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

which I believe has the same structure as the link given above. Then I tried to construct the loss and optimizer as follows;

```py
x_train  = np.linspace(0,2,100,endpoint=True)#Generate 100 points in the [0,2] interval
x_t      = np.zeros((len(x_train),1))
x_t[:,0] = x_train

x = tf.constant(x_t)
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    variables = model.trainable_variables
    tape.watch(x)
    tape.watch(variables)
    y_pred  = model(x,training=True)
    #dy_dx = tape.gradient(y_pred,x)
    #print(dy_dx)
y = tf.reshape(y_pred,x.shape).numpy()
dy_dx = tape.gradient(y_pred,x)
A = (1+3*(x**2))/(1+x+x**3)
t_loss = tf.reshape(dy_dx,x.shape) + (x + A)*y - x**3 - 2*x - A * x**2
loss = tf.reshape(tf.reduce_mean(t_loss)+(y[0]-1)**2,())

with tf.GradientTape() as tape2:
    tape2.watch(model.trainable_weights)
    logits  = model(x,training=True)
grads = tape.gradient(loss,model.trainable_weights) # it has been tested with trainable_variables as well
```

Here `t_loss` is simply eq. 4 in [1902.05563](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.05563) and `loss` additionally has the boundary condition implemented as `(y[0]-1)**2`. However since my `grads` are `[None, None, None, None]` my optimizer fails.

```py
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
### output
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['l1/kernel:0', 'l1/bias:0', 'output/kernel:0', 'output/bias:0'].
```

would be great if anybody can show me how to write a working example of this differential eq solver. Thanks!

---

**Additional Info**

A similar question has been asked in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288258/derivative-in-loss-function-in-keras) which I tried to rewrite my approach using it. So the modified approach is as follows using the same `model`

```py
def _loss_tensor(y_true,y_pred,x_train):
    x = tf.constant(x_train)
    dy_dx = tf.keras.backend.gradients(y_pred,x)
    lq = (1+3*(x1**2))/(1+x1+x1**3)
    t_loss = (dy_dx+(x+lq)*y_pred-x**3-2*x-lq*x*x)
    return tf.reduce_mean(t_loss)+(y_pred[0]-1)**2
def loss_func(x_train):
    def loss(y_true,y_pred):
        return _loss_tensor(y_true,y_pred,x_train)
    return loss
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-2)
model.compile(loss=loss_func(model.inputs), # tried x_t, model.input as well but all gave same result
              optimizer=optimizer)
model.train_on_batch(x_t)
#also tried
#model.fit(x_t,epochs=5,verbose=1)
### Output
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['l1/kernel:0', 'l1/bias:0', 'output/kernel:0', 'output/bias:0'].
```

However I'm still getting the exact same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it's not possible to use Keras to define a loss function in model class (or I couldn't find a solution for it). So instead I solved the problem through low-level TensorFlow (v2.3+ note that v1's syntax is quite different);

```py
x_train  = np.linspace(0,2,100,endpoint=True)#Generate 100 points in the [0,2] interval
x_t      = np.zeros((len(x_train),1))
x_t[:,0] = x_train

inputs = tf.keras.Input(name='inputs',shape=(1),dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
hidden = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation=tf.nn.sigmoid,name='hidden')
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation=None,name='output')
model  = tf.keras.Sequential([inputs, hidden, output ])

epochs = 50000
Adam   = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-2)

x = tf.constant(x_t,dtype=float)
trainable_vars = model.trainable_variables
losses = []
for ix in range(epochs):
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        tape.watch(x)
        tape.watch(trainable_vars)
        y = model(x,training=True)
        dy_dx = tape.gradient(y,x)  
        A = (1+3*x**2)/(1+x+x**3)
        t_loss = (dy_dx + (x + A) * y - x**3 - 2*x - x**2*A)**2
        loss  =  tf.reduce_mean(t_loss)+(y[0]-1)**2
        tape.watch(loss)

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
    Adam.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
    losses.append(loss.numpy()[0])
```